# in Grails 3.3.x with the 'GORM Logical Delete' plugin what are the differences between Criteria Query and Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria

The [GORM Logical Delete plugin documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/gorm-logical-delete/snapshot/index.html) says:

> The plugin supports a variety of query types in addition to dynamic finders, see examples below:
> 5.1. Criteria Query
>
> ```
> def criteria = Person.createCriteria()
> def results = criteria {
>     or {
>         eq("userName", "Ben")
>         eq("userName", "Nirav")
>     }
> }
> ```

and then goes on to specify:

> Hibernate Criteria and HQL queries are NOT supported by this plugin.

Running the tests from the logical delete plugin for:
`def criteria = Person.createCriteria()`
I receive an object of type:

`grails.gorm.CriteriaBuilder`

In my own Grails 3.3.1 project when I call `createCriteria()` on my domain object I receive a:

`grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder`

So my question is how to differentiate between these two situations. In a Grails/Hibernate project is it even possible to have non-hibernate Criteria? Or what good does the logical delete plugin do if it doesn't work for my criteria?

Comment: I think he meant by that, that `deleted` field is NOT injected into HQL and plain Hib criteria queries

Comment: But Grails is always with hibernate, right? So my question is what the criteria example shows if it's not usable in a grails application

Comment: No, it just means that you have to insert 'deleted ' flag into HQL queries yourself, as the pluigin doesn't do it

Comment: For HQL that's fine. My question is about criteria queries which are specifically shown in the example above. In what case is that example usable if it doesn't work for hibernate criteria queries.